# How do I use latest version in table_changes function for a delta table?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I have a query which gives me the latest version of a delta table in the following format

(Query 1):

```
%sql
SELECT VERSION FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY dbo.customers LIMIT 1)
```

This gives me output like this:

[image: Output of the above query]

I have a query for table_changes which I'm using it in this way

(Query 2):

```
%sql
select * from table_changes('dbo.customers', 3)
```

It gives me the records of whatever changes were there in version 3 which is the latest version.

Now, when I am trying to do it in 1 query instead of 2, I attempted the following

(Query 3):

```
%sql
select * from table_changes('dbo.customers', SELECT VERSION FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY dbo.customers LIMIT 1))
```

It gives me a syntax error.

I understand that (Query 1) is returning a table but I just want to use the value of the first row in the second argument of the table_changes function.

How do I use it or is there any better way to get the result in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use widget in databricks to use the value in `table_changes` as below.

```
%python
import json
result = spark.sql("SELECT  VERSION  FROM (DESCRIBE  HISTORY  delta.`/sampDelta/names/` LIMIT  1)").toJSON()
j_obj = json.loads(result.collect()[0])
print(j_obj['VERSION'])
dbutils.widgets.text('vers', str(j_obj['VERSION']))
```

[image]

Then use that value in function as **Integer**.

```
%sql
select  *  from  table_changes('delta.`/sampDelta/names/`', int('${vers}'))
```

[image]

Comment: This is something I have already tried. What I have asked is if there was a way we can do it in a single SQL statement. But as it turns out the 2nd parameter only accepts only 2 things....i.e. table_changes(table, <BIGINT or datetime>). So this won't be possible I think unless there are some updates to this function by Databricks in future.

Comment: Yes. we can not give select expression in `table_changes` function as it accepts only `BIGINT` and `datetime`.  Is it ok with the pyspark solution?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I have already tried it with PySpark way & that's not what I was looking for actually. I have to use it in a SQL cell in a pipeline. 
But thanks for the answer anyways!